# Grails NoSuchField exception because of wrong denpendecy version of apache http core

Tags: java, grails, dependency-management, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have Grails 2.0.4 application that depends on a jar that depends on org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1

I'm getting a NoSuchField exception which I managed to track down to org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicLineParser.INSTANCE.

This field is only present from httpcore 4.3, before this version the field was BasicLineParser.DEFAULT instead

My BuildConfig.groovy is like:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
}
```

Running the dependecy report I found out the there is a signpost-commonshttp4 by oauth.signpost that depends on httpcore:4.0.1 which is probably the root cause of my issue, because it doesn't have the INSTANCE property.

I've tried to exclude this dependency adding

```
runtime('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.1'){
    excludes 'httpcore'
}
```

with no success.

Is there any other way to prevent the code to use the older library version?

Regards

**RESOLVED**

I managed to resolve this issue adding an extra dependecies configuration

```
build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
```

along with the runtime

Thank you all

Comment: Have you also tried `exclude 'httpcore'`? And are you sure this is the only dependency to exclude from?

Comment: Did you run "dependency-report" after excluding 'httpcore' from 'signpost-commonshttp4'? from where "httpcore" it is resolving now ?